# How to replace ~ with $HOME properly using sed inline?

Tags: bash, sed, makefile

The idea is to transform this ~/.local/bin let's say to this /home/user1/.local/bin

so I have a Makefile that basically a try to get it to work but it doesn't

```
system: 
    sed -i 's/~/$HOME/g' myapp.desktop
```

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Version=0.4
Type=Application

Name=Desktop App

Exec=~/.local/bin/desktop_app
Terminal=false
```

Comment: Change the delimiter. Use double quotes so the variable can expand `sed -i "s@~@$HOME@g" myapp.desktop`

Comment: Using `-i` in `sed` is always a bad idea.  Using it in a Makefile recipe seems like a terrible idea.

Comment: That value of the `Exec` key in the original desktop file is malformed relative to the desktop file specification (which requires the executable to be specified either as simple filename or a full path).  Did you receive the file that way from a third party?  Because if you created that file yourself then there may be better alternatives that don't require the kind of tilde translation you're asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for your constructive feedback, yea I created it, I just need to find a way to read current home directory in full-path in the makefile

Comment: Giving some context, it's a python cookiecutter to create a binary and a .desktop app, make is just syntactic sugar to top a multistep process

Comment: @WilliamPursell not sure why you think so... ? there is always room to learn

Comment: This seems more like a bug to fix in the `.desktop` template(?) than something you should post-process from the Makefile. Tildes are *shell* shortcuts, not actual directory names.

Comment: @Omar `-i` is not standard; you will eventually run make where `sed` treats `-i` as an error.  Since `system` appears to be a `.PHONY` target, this recipe will likely run `sed` more than once on the file, and all subsequent runs will be no-ops.  Will those runs change the timestamp of the file if they don't change it?  Maybe, but it depends on the implementation of `sed`.  Make relies heavily on timestamps, so that seems fragile.  Overall, this recipe just feels wrong.

Comment: To emphasize what William said above -- `-i` behaves in two different incompatible ways between GNU and BSD sed, so as soon as someone runs your code on a non-GNU system _even if it does have `sed -i`_, it can fail.

Answer (score 3):

Since your own code is generating the tilde-including pseudo-path, I guess you can be confident of the form.  This is important, because in general, the shell's [tilde expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) behavior is not wholly consistent with the simple translation you want to perform.  The shell's tilde expansion differs in at least these ways:

- it applies only when the tilde is the first character of the word
- it affects a prefix of the subject word up to but excluding the first slash (`/`), if any
- it affects *only* a prefix such as described above, not any other tilde appearances in the subject word

A simple substitution such as your example `sed` command suggests will have the same effect as the shell's tilde expansion on some possible inputs, but different effects on others, so again, it's important that you are controlling the form of the input.

For your particular case, you seem to want the shell to expand `$HOME`, but single-quoting it suppresses that.  On the other hand, you need `make` to *not* expand `$H` (to nothing, probably), so you need to escape the `$` from `make`.  The resulting rule might look like this:

```
system: 
        sed -i "s/~/$${HOME}/g" myapp.desktop
```

There are other problems with that, though, such as that the `-i` option is non-portable.  Some `sed`s don't have it at all, and behavior varies among those that do have it (BSD-style `sed` *vs* GNU `sed`, for example).

---

Since you're generating this desktop file via a code generator, however, the first question that comes to mind is **why are you not generating it with the wanted `Exec` path in the first place?**

The only answer that make sense to me is that you are generating the desktop file in a separate context from the one(s) in which the software will be installed.  In that case, however, the next question is **why are you not taking advantage of the standard tools for working with desktop files?**  In particular, it would be appropos to use [`desktop-file-install`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/desktop-file-install.1) to both install the file into the user's `.local/share/applications`, *and*, simultaneously, to set the correct value of the `Exec` key within.  Example:

```
INSTALL_BIN = "$${HOME}"/.local/bin
INSTALL_DESKTOP = "$${HOME}"/.local/share/applications
install:
        mkdir -p $(INSTALL_BIN)
        mkdir -p $(INSTALL_DESKTOP)
        install -m 0755 desktop-app $(INSTALL_BIN)
        desktop-file-install --dir=$(INSTALL_DESKTOP) --set-key=Exec --set-value=$(INSTALL_BIN)/desktop-app
```